# Troubleshoot System Error 64

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

When I run from the command prompt:

> net view

I get

> System error 64 has occurred.
>
> The specified network name is no longer available.

What troubleshooting steps should I be taking.
Running Windows 10.

Comment: Try __net help view__ or __net /?__

Comment: Try to find out why the network is dropping. Perhaps a problem of router, interference on the line, or maybe a flaky VPN.